# Web3 how to keep connection to web socket

Tags: node.js, blockchain, ethereum, web3js

Im trying to listen to Transfer events but it works for couple of minutes then process terminates. I believe thats because of the blockchain node I use but not sure. Can't find anything other so.

How can I keep the connection and Listen to Transfer events 24/7

```
  const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://bsc-ws-node.nariox.org:443'))
  const contract = await new web3.eth.Contract(
    ABI,
    contracts[0]
  )

  contract.events
    .Transfer({
      fromBlock: 'latest',
      filter: { from: contracts[1] }
    })
    .on('data', async (event: EventData) => {
      const {
        transactionHash,
        returnValues: { value }
      } = event
       ....
    })
```

Comment: Try other blockchain nodes https://ethereumnodes.com/

Comment: Im looking for BSC nodes

Answer (score 0):

```
const s = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://bsc-ws-node.nariox.org:443', {
    clientConfig: {
        keepalive: true,
        keepaliveInterval: 60000
    }
});
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?